# How to convert xls file to csv file in access 2000 VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need a piece of code which can convert xls file to csv file.
I am using ms access 2000 and is writing code inside it with VBA.

I searched google and many solution failed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I tried the solution and it failed. It said Error 1004 cannot access the file (which file? It didn't said).
[image]

My Code:

```
Sub XlsToCsv(Fullname As String)
    filename = Left(Fullname, InStrRev(Fullname, "."))

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    Set objExcelBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Fullname)

    objExcel.Application.Visible = False
    objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    objExcelBook.SaveAs filename & "csv", 23

    objExcel.Application.Quit
    objExcel.Quit

    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objExcelBook = Nothing


End Sub
```

How it is called:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "getInboundCdr", strPathToSave, True
XlsToCsv (strPathToSave)
```

getInboundCdr is the name of the query.

Comment: And sometimes it just freezed.

Answer (score 2):

This VBScript solution

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=18188

should be very easy to port to Access VBA. If you have difficulties with porting, describe in detail what kind of problem you have.